# Error de enrutamiento en servicio de Windows

Tags: vb.net, windows, ms-access, servicio

Hola realice un servicio de Windows hecho en VB.NET y Access el cual hace ciertos cálculos de inventarios.
El problema me surgió al momento de conectarme, como si no encontrara la ruta de las bases de Access, cabe mencionar que si escribo la ruta:

```
 C:/CarpetaX/Base1.mdb
```

Si funciona de manera local, pero si hago la CarpetaX en una unidad de red para acceder ejemplo:

```
W:/Base1.mdb
```

No funciona.

La carpeta ya le puse todos los permisos para compartir en la red. y si escribo en el explorador de Windows la ruta **W:/Base1.mdb** si me abre la carpeta con las bases.

Adjunto imagen con la configuración del **AppConfig**

[image: appconfig]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y leas :  [ask] para que te podamos ayudar y evites votos negativos.

Comment: No te funciona porque W:/Base1.mdb es una ruta DOS
Prueba añadir la ruta de acceso UNC de red de W: (es la ruta que utilizar para montar W) Como ejemplo \\Server2\Share\Test\Base1.mdb

Comment: También acabo de ver que W:/Base1.mdb puede que no sea correcto. Prueba a W:\Base1.mdb
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats